# Mathematica showing error for NDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, manipulate

```
Manipulate[
 Evaluate[sol = 
   NDSolve[{x''[t] + c*Sin[x[t]] == 0, x'[0] == a[[1]], 
     x[0] == a[[2]]}, x, {t, 0, tmax}]]; {Dynamic[
   Plot[Evaluate[{x[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}]]}, {c, 0, 10}, {tmax, 0, 
  20}, {{a, {0, 2.96706}, "initial condition"}, {0, 0}, {10, 10}}, 
 ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

I want to vary `t` as well as `c`... but it gives me an error:

> Plot::plld : Endpoints for t in {t,0,FE`tmax$$212} must have distinct 
>   machine-precision numerical values.

How can I overcome this problem??

Comment: Have you considered `ParametricNDSolve`?

Comment: i used ParametricNDSolve, but it's showing error again... "{ParametricNDSolve[{\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\"x\", \"\[Prime]\[Prime]\",
MultilineFunction->None]\)[t]==0,\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\"x\", \"\[Prime]\",
MultilineFunction->None]\)[0]==0,x[0]==2.96706`},x,{t,0,0}]} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing."

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, what are you trying to solve?  This is some sort of linear oscillator?

Comment: its a Non linear Oscillator .. which time period depend on theta as well as c...

Comment: Maybe you could give `tmax` a value distinct from `0`, just as it says in the error message?  (Note also that the message name for the error clearly indicates it's a problem with `Plot`, not `NDSolve`.)

Answer (score 2):

Formatting clean-up and removing redundant `Evaluate` and `Dynamic`.

In addition, `tmax` and `c` begin at 1 as opposed to 0.

```
Manipulate[{
  sol = NDSolve[{x''[t] + c*Sin[x[t]] == 0,
     x'[0] == a[[1]], x[0] == a[[2]]}, x, {t, 0, tmax}];
  Plot[Evaluate[{x[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}]},
 {c, 1, 10}, {tmax, 1,20}, {{a, {0, 2.96706}, "initial condition"}, 
   {0, 0}, {10, 10}}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image]

Solved using Raspberry Pi 3

Comment: @xyz Did this answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps this is a possible answer:

```
Clear[a, b, c, tMax, x, t];
tMax = 20;
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[t] + c*Sin[x[t]] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
   x[0] == 2.96706}, x, {t, 0, tMax}, {c}]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[sol[c][t], {c, 0, 10, 1}]], {t, 0, tMax}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

With Manipulate also added, perhaps this can be done:

```
Clear[a, b, c, tMax, x, t];
tMax = 20;
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x''[t] + c*Sin[x[t]] == 0, x'[0] == 0, 
   x[0] == 2.96706}, x, {t, 0, tMax}, {c}]


Manipulate[
 Plot[sol[c][t], {t, 0, tMax}, PlotRange -> All], {c, 0, 10, 1}]
```

Comment: but i want to see the Variation of the function with changing time as well as c... Where act as an variable.. is it possible to do so ???

Comment: @xyz Does the new edit help?

Comment: Simply Sin[x] is a function of t ..because "x" is a function of [t] ... So Is there any possibility that "t" acts as a variable like c??

Comment: Manipulate does not working ...

Comment: Perhaps I'm failing to understand... It is an ode in `t` that is being solved. What other variation in time is necessary here besides solving this ode 'in time '?

Comment: @xyz made the correction.  Oops! My mistake.