# Want to remove unnecessary message

Tags: plotting, warning-messages

```
Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[{t, t}, {t, 0, s}],
  {s, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

This code is working in *Mathematica*, but generates messages (`ParametricPlot::plld`). I tried `Quiet`, but result was still the same.

I looked at `Off`,  but not understand how to use it.

Comment: The reason for the message is that `ParametricPlot[{0,0}]` doesn't work. If you do something like `Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{t, t}, {t, 0, s}], {s, 0.001, 1, 0.1}]` instead (note the `s` initial value to `0.001`) it will stop issuing the message.

Comment: The bigger question here is why does `Quiet[ParametricPlot[{t, t}, {t, 0, s}]];` issue a message?

Comment: I think it's because it evaluates inside the `Quiet`, comes back unevaluated, then reevaluates upon return. Try `f /; (Print[1]; 1/0) = Null; Quiet[f]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120868/mathematica-showing-error-for-ndsolve

Comment: Perhaps this might be a helpful example: `Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[{Sin[2 t], Cos[3 t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Mesh -> {{s}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Red, MeshShading -> {ColorData[97][1], None}, 
  PlotRange -> 1],
 {s, 0, 2 Pi}]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message is

> ParametricPlot: Endpoints for t [...] must have distinct machine-precision numerical values.

The endpoints for `t` are `0` and `s`, so when `s` is `0`, `ParametricPlot` tries to plot `t` from `0` to `0` and produces this message.

You can solve the problem by setting the lower bound of `s` to a value strictly larger than `0`:

```
Manipulate[ParametricPlot[{t,t},{t,0,s}],{s,0.1,1,0.1}]]
```